# How to keep profiteroles fresh

Tags: storage-method, storage, pastry, freshness

I am having family over for dinner soon, and would like to make profiteroles for dessert. I will, however, be busy during the daytime and will only have an hour or so before people arrive for dinner, in which time I will need to cook the main course.

My question - can I make the profiteroles (just the choux bun - filling and sauce kept separate) the day before?

If there is a way, how should they be kept, to keep them fresh and not either dried out or far too soft/stale?